# Compare two JSON Arrays and rearrange new JSON Array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is the my first JSON Array format...

```
[
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "caption": "caption1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2345",
        "caption": "caption2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3456",
        "caption": "caption3"
    }
]
```

and here is another JSON Array Format

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "value": "value11"
        },
        {
            "id": "2345",
            "value": "value12"
        },
        {
            "id": "3456",
            "value": "value13"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "value": "value21"
        },
        {
            "id": "2345",
            "value": "value22"
        },
        {
            "id": "3456",
            "value": "value23"
        }
    ]
]
```

The above mentioned Two JSON Arrays, i need to compare each one with Id and need to format a new JSON Array with caption and value using javascript.

```
[
    [
        {
            "caption" : "caption1",
            "value":"value11"
        },
       {
            "caption" : "caption2",
            "value":"value12"
       },
       {
            "caption" : "caption3",
            "value":"value13"
       }
    ],
    [
       {
            "caption" : "caption1",
            "value":"value21"
       },
       {
           "caption" : "caption2",
           "value":"value22"
       },
       {
            "caption" : "caption3",
            "value":"value23"
       }
    ]
]
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What did you try? Sounds easy enough, but it also sounds like you just want use to write it for you. Did you run to some issues? Do you know loops?

Comment: this is not a json string, this is a java script array. you can find the diff by looping through.

 if you're using underscore.js i've written this function to find diff between two "objects". https://gist.github.com/astroanu/cf76c97de0f8d2e490f5

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways. Below I show two variants:

***Option 1: Pure JavaScript***

In this example the program preindex first array for faster access to it data, and then loops over second array with map() function to create new array of arrays:

```
// Create index version of first array
var aix = {};
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    aix[arr1[i].id] = arr1[i].caption;
}

// Loop over array of arrays
var res1 = arr2.map(function(arr22){
    return arr22.map(function(a){
        return {caption:aix[a.id], value:a.value};
    }
});
```

***Option 2: Using special SQL library (Alasql)***

Here, you can JOIN to arrays automatically with special SQL statement:

```
var res2 = arr2.map(function(a){
    return alasql('SELECT arr1.caption, a.[value] \
                       FROM ? a JOIN ? arr1 USING id',[a,arr1]);
});
```

You can try these variants in working snippet below or play with it [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf806jja/).

(Disclaimer: I am the author of [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql))

```js
var arr1 = [
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "caption": "caption1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2345",
        "caption": "caption2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3456",
        "caption": "caption3"
    }
];

var arr2 = [
    [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "value": "value11"
        },
        {
            "id": "2345",
            "value": "value12"
        },
        {
            "id": "3456",
            "value": "value13"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "value": "value21"
        },
        {
            "id": "2345",
            "value": "value22"
        },
        {
            "id": "3456",
            "value": "value23"
        }
    ]
];
// JavaScript version
var aix = {};
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    aix[arr1[i].id] = arr1[i].caption;
}
var res1 = arr2.map(function(arr22){
    return arr22.map(function(a){
        return {caption:aix[a.id], value:a.value};
    });
});

document.getElementById("res1").textContent = JSON.stringify(res1);

// Alasql version
var res2 = arr2.map(function(a){
    return alasql('SELECT arr1.caption, a.[value] FROM ? a JOIN ? arr1 USING id',[a,arr1]);
});

document.getElementById("res2").textContent = JSON.stringify(res2);
```

```html
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>

<p>Varian 1: JavaScript</p>
    <div id="res1"></div>
<p>Variant 2: Alasql</p>
<div id="res2"></div>
```